# Load text file on winform and display result depend on condition

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a text file (*.txt) like:

Name1(tab)Address1(tab)Age1
Name2(tab)Address2(tab)Age2
...

And I want display on winform like

Name1 Age1 Young(Old)
Name2 Age2 Young(Old)
...

Young if age <40 and old if age>=40
How i do that. 
Thanks to Everyone.

My code is:
      OpenFileDialog opd = new OpenFileDialog();

```
    private void btnOpenfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Open txt file
        opd.Filter = "TXT|*.txt";
        //Choose File
        if (opd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lblFilename.Text = opd.SafeFileName;

        }
        var dulieu = File.ReadAllLines(opd.FileName);
        ////////////////////
        if (dulieu.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var cellValues in dulieu.Skip(0))
             {
            var cellArray = cellValues
                .Split(new[] {'\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (cellArray.Length == dtgBangketqua.Columns.Count)
                dtgBangketqua.Rows.Add(cellArray);
             }

        }


    }
```

I want when i click Value button and will add one column behind Age column name Result and display Young or Old.
In this Datagridview, i hide the column Address.
[Here is my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQjOA.png)

Comment: Please show some attempt at doing this yourself. First consider how you will import the text from the file, secondly think about how you will split the text into relevant sections then lastly consider how you will send this data to your view.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what are you actually asking? How to load a file? How to create a form? How to display values on that form? How the `if`-statement for the age should look like? If someone can do all the work for you?

Comment: I use OpenFileDialog to open txt file. And display on winform by anything as long as satisfy the condition (maybe datatable or anything else).

Answer (score 0):

I assume your file include like this: "Name1;Address1;Age1" instead of (tab),use ";".

```
string txt = File.ReadAllText(YOUR_PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE);
string[]items = txt.Split(";".ToCharArray());
string Name = items[0];
string Address = items[1];
string Age = items[2];
```

---

### It is just reading file and spliting it. but you have to use loop to execute this code block for each line. And then use your conditions.

And for you Age condition :
    if(Int(Age) >= 40) Age = Age + "(Old)"

Comment: This text file is release by another program. It contains too many lines. :(